# Manipulate formula and several value on the Plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want to show the numerical results of (universal) gravitation.

However, how to give the value in the control bar?

```
G = 6.67259*10^(-11);
Manipulate[
   Show[Plot[G*(M*m)/R^2, {R, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 2*10^(-8)}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{r, G*(M*m)/r^2}]}]], {
    {M, 5}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m, 1}, 1, 10, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 0.3}, 0.1, 1, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Text@Style["F=", Black], 
    TrackedSymbols :> {M, m, r}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

G = 6.67259*10^(-11);

Manipulate[
 F = G*(M*m)/r^2;
 Show[Plot[G*(M*m)/R^2, {R, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 2*10^(-8)}}],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large],
    Tooltip[Point[#], #] &[{r, G*(M*m)/r^2}]}]],
 {{M, 5}, 1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 1}, 1, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 0.3}, 0.1, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Text@Style[StringForm["F = ``", Dynamic[F]], Black],
 TrackedSymbols :> {M, m, r}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How to add physical units? Such as 0.3(metre) 1(kg) 3.7×10^-9(N)

Comment: Use [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html). If after reading and applying the documentation you have issues, post a new question with the details. The use of quantities has nothing to do with the original issue of this post.